# Two Symfony Forms, Only First Form Submits

Tags: php, symfony

I have used log statements in both of the `if(isSubmitted && isValid) {}` statements, even when the second form is submitted I still get the log message from the first form.

The second form's submit logic is never reached. If I remove the first form's code then the second form submits no problem. It just seems to be an issue with having multiple forms in one controller.

**PHP Controller**

```
<?php

namespace Worx\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\Autowire;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class BCBusinessEntityMappingController extends AbstractController {

  public HttpClientInterface $client;
  private \mysqli|false $database;

  public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client, #[Autowire('%env(DBHOST)%')] private $dbhost, #[Autowire('%env(DBUSER)%')] private $dbuser, #[Autowire('%env(DBPASS)%')] private $dbpass, #[Autowire('%env(DBNAME)%')] private $dbname) {
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->database = mysqli_connect($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname, 3306);
  }

  /**
   * @throws \Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface
   */
  #[Route('/test', name: 'test')]
  public function load(Request $request): Response {
    // Grab our store context from the session.
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $context = $session->get('store_context');

    // See if we already have the seller saved. If so we will show this
    // as the default value for the form.
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare("SELECT SELLER STATEMENT");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $context);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->get_result();

    $seller = '';
    if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
      $seller = $results->fetch_object()->seller;
    }

    $seller_form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, ['attr' => ['id' => 'seller-form']])
      ->add('seller', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Seller Entity', 'data' => $seller])
      ->add('submit1', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Submit'])
      ->getForm();

    $seller_form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($seller_form->isSubmitted() && $seller_form->isValid()) {
      $seller_form_data = $seller_form->getData();

      if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
        // Update existing record.
        $stmt = $this->database->prepare("UPDATE STATEMENT");
      }
      else {
        // Insert new record.
        $stmt = $this->database->prepare("INSERT INTO STATEMENT");
      }
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $context, $seller_form_data['seller']);
      $stmt->execute();

      return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
    }

    $buyer_form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, ['attr' => ['id' => 'business-form']])
      ->add('customer_id', IntegerType::class, ['label' => 'Customer Id'])
      ->add('business_entity', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Business Entity'])
      ->add('submit2', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Submit'])
      ->getForm();

    $buyer_form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($buyer_form->isSubmitted() && $buyer_form->isValid()) {
      $buyer_form_data = $buyer_form->getData();

      $stmt = $this->database->prepare("INSERT INTO STATEMENT");
      $stmt->bind_param("sis", $context,$buyer_form_data['customer_id'], $buyer_form_data['business_entity']);
      if (TRUE === $stmt->execute()) {
        return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
      }
      else {
        // todo - return a message var for twig that will say an error.
        //  Look into using $stmt->error; This should be a string containing
        //  the error message.
      }
    }

    // Get the current group mapping data.
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare("SELECT id, customer_id, business_entity FROM business_entity_mapping WHERE context=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $context);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->get_result();
    $rows = '';
    if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
      $rows = $results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    return $this->render('business_entity_mapping_form.html.twig', [
      'seller_form' => $seller_form->createView(),
      'business_entity_mapping_form' => $buyer_form->createView(),
      'rows' => $rows,
    ]);
  }

}
```

**Twig File**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <link href="{{ asset('css/table.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="{{ asset('css/business_entity.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  {% if seller_form is not empty %}
    <div class="seller-form">
      {{ form(seller_form) }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% if business_entity_mapping_form is not empty %}
    <div class="business-entity-mapping-form">
      {{ form(business_entity_mapping_form) }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}

  <table class="styled-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer ID</th>
      <th>Business Entity</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% if rows is not empty %}
      {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="cell-border">{{ row.customer_id }}</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="cell-border">{{ row.business_entity }}</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="cell-border center-text">
              <a href="{{ path('bc_business_entity_edit', {'id': row.id}) }}">edit</a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="center-text">
              <a href="{{ path('bc_business_entity_delete', {'id': row.id}) }}">delete</a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <tr>
        <td>No Records Found!</td>
      </tr>
    {% endif %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It's probably because you're redirecting after the submit and so the first form works and the second form never gets processed. Have a look at the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/multiple_buttons.html) regarding multiple form submit buttons.

Comment: In order for me to have multiple forms on one page, I needed to create a FormType for each form. This allows Symfony to know which form was submitted, otherwise it just takes the post data and applies it to the first form.

Answer (score 0):

The two forms need to be clearly separated and this should work.

```
<div class="seller_form">
  {{ form_start(seller_form) }}
  ...
  {{ form_row(seller_form.submit1) }}
  {{ form_end(seller_form) }}
</div>
<div class="business_entity_mapping_form">
  {{ form_start(business_entity_mapping_form) }}
  ...
  {{ form_row(business_entity_mapping_form.submit2) }}
  {{ form_end(business_entity_mapping_form) }}
</div>
```

Comment: I added my twig code to the question. Does this also mean I would need to display each field separately with `{{ form_widget() }}`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still submits the first form.

Comment: Try the Nicodemuz solution.
If that doesn't work, you can use the submit() function in JS
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a block prefix:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#block-prefix

This is because you are calling `createFormBuilder` with first argument as `null` for both forms.